# Importing caffe results in ImportError: "No module named google.protobuf.internal" (import enum_type_wrapper)

Tags: python, caffe, protocol-buffers

I installed Anaconda Python on my machine.  When I start the Python Interpreter and type "import caffe" in the Python shell, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf.internal
```

I have the following files:

```
wire_format_lite_inl.h
wire_format_lite.h
wire_format.h
unknown_field_set.h
text_format.h
service.h
repeated_field.h
reflection_ops.h
message_lite.h
message.h
generated_message_util.h
extension_set.h
descriptor.proto
descriptor.h
generated_message_reflection.h
generated_enum_reflection.h
dynamic_message.h
descriptor.pb.h
descriptor_database.h
```

What files do I need so the import will work?  Is there an "internal.h" file that is required?

Comment: How did you install protobuf? via conda or apt-get or from source? Did you also install the protobuf python package?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did not install protobuf at all.  I will check our GitHub for the Protobuf Python package.  I don't think it is there, but it will be worth a check.  In case it is not, I requested Google Protobuf from the approved software list to be installed on the OS where I am working.

Comment: @PyNerd, yeah you didn't install protobuf, tensorflow might have installed it, with a different version which is not working with caffe, So if you uninstall and install it again, it'll install latest version of protobuf which might not be compatible with tensorflow but the import caffe will succeed. Usually this happens if we try to install tensorflow with a specific version.

Answer (score 36):

This is probably because you have two python environments in your machine, the one provided by your linux distribution(`pip`) and the other by the anaconda environment (`/home/username/anaconda2/bin/pip`).

## Try installing protobuf for both environments to be sure

`pip install protobuf`

`/home/username/anaconda2/bin/pip install protobuf`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Anaconda, do `conda install protobuf`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ubuntu, try installing protobuf using

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf
```

It solved the same problem that I faced.

Comment: This did not work for me, but `sudo apt-get install python-protobuf` did.

Comment: I my case `sudo apt install python3-protobuf` made it work

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to fix it:

```
pip install grpcio
pip install protobuf
```

When have multiple python version use: as suggested by aimuch.

```
/usr/local/bin/pip2 install protobuf
/usr/local/bin/pip2 install grpcio
```

Comment: `pip uninstall protobuf`
`pip install protobuf`
it worked for me.

Comment: yeah probably grpcio has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: For me, using `pip` caused further problems (started asking me to downgrade protobuf). As noted in another answer, `conda install protobuf` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the python envirnment confusion.

```sh
# check where pip2
$ where pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
/usr/bin/pip2

# check where pip
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

On my computer, I have two pip2(I install caffe using python2 env), so I used `/usr/local/bin/pip2 install protobuf` solved this problem.

```sh
/usr/local/bin/pip2 install protobuf
```

Comment: This solve it. /usr/local/bin/pip2 install protobuf