# ImportError: No module named google.protobuf.internal

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I have generated a proto3_pb2.py using the protoc compiler. While importing this file I am getting the import error "No module named google.protobuf.internal". I have downloaded the protoc binary from the github page for python and pointed the PATH environment variable to the path of binary. However still I am getting the import error.

PS: I cannot use pip/conda to solve this problem.

Can anybody point out what I am missing.

Comment: I would think you should try to install via pip instead. Seems like a missing dependency. Although you might not be using grpc, try doing pip install grpcio and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. @Jason I cannot use pip or conda

Comment: Does this help? There is one of the answers using apt-get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666241/importing-caffe-results-in-importerror-no-module-named-google-protobuf-interna

Comment: I cannot use apt-get

Comment: Ubuntu that cant use pip, apt-get...how do you install anything on your system?