# how to installe caffe in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, caffe, pycaffe

I try to install caffe but I still have a problem in the installation, I tried several tutorials but still I couldn't do it
File "/home/lynda/caffe/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 6, in 
from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666241/importing-caffe-results-in-importerror-no-module-named-google-protobuf-interna

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the module google . You need to install it

```bash
sudo python3 -m pip install google
```

or

```bash
sudo python -m pip install google
```